# JAXB root element gets set to type during marshalling

Tags: xml, groovy, jaxb, marshalling

I asked a question before about marshalling a jdom element. I never got that to work, so I switched to using a java object instead. This enabled me to almost get my program to work. I am however facing the last hurdle.

So in that class i'm trying to marshal I have the following field:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ReportElement")
class ReportElement{

    More fields....

    @XmlElement(name = "Content", namespace = "some:name:space:1")
    Object content
}
```

The content will be set to a class, which has the following root element:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ContentInfoType", propOrder = [
    order here
])
@XmlRootElement(name = "ContentInfo", namespace = "some:name:space:2")
class ContentInfoType implements ReportProperty {
```

It marshals everything as I want it, except this bit:

```
<ns5:Content xsi:type="ns2:ContentInfoType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

All the fields of ContentInfoType gets set correctly, but I dont understand why my root element of ContentInfoType is not getting set as an xml node like this:

```
<ns2:ContentInfo></ContentInfo>
```

Here is my marshalling code:

```
 static <T> Element serializeGenericObjectToXmlTypeElement(T object, boolean removeDeclaration = false, List<String> objectList = []) {
        JAXBContext jc
        if(objectList.size() != 0){
            String packageString = object.getClass().getPackage().getName()
            for(String s : objectList){
                packageString += ":" + s
            }
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(packageString)
        } else{
            jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass())
        }
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller()

        if (removeDeclaration) {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true)
        }

        Writer writer = new StringWriter()
        marshaller.marshal(object, writer)
        def xmlString = writer.toString()
        def stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString)
        def builder = new SAXBuilder()
        def doc = builder.build(stringReader)
        def elem = doc.getRootElement()
        MyXMLFormatter xmlFormatter = new MyXMLFormatter(elem)
        Element element2 = xmlFormatter.formatXml(elem)
        return element2
    }
```

Whenever I need to marshal more than one class I send in a list with the package names of the classes that needs to be marshalled.

You can ignore the MyXMLFormatter. It already at

```
marshaller.marshal(object, writer)
```

That the output isn't what i desire.

Does anyone have any idea about why the behaviour is the way it is?

PS:
If I marshal ContentInfoType on alone (I have a scenario, where i only need xml of that), it works fine, and i get an xml element with ContentInfo. But when ContentInfoType gets set to the "Object content", of my ReportElement class it doesn't work.

EDIT: I just made an edit, since i didn't get all the annotations of my contentinfotype class. Maybe it's the @XmlType annotation that's the cause of this.

Comment: You get an `xsi:type` attribute because the `content` field is of type `Object`. When you unmarshal this (XML -> Java objects) then JAXB needs to know what type of object to create; it looks at the `xsi:type` attribute to understand what type of object it should instantiate. The element name is `Content` and not `ContentInfo` because `Content` is the name you specified in the `@XmlElement` annotation on the `content` field in class `ReportElement`.

Comment: Yeah okay. That makes sense. Do you know how I would get ContentInfo as a child element instead of a type? Because I cannot really see a way around using object, when my content, can be any class in my system (In theory)